# Inserting values of an map with vectors

Tags: c++, dictionary, vector

I have the following map:

`std::map<u_long, std::vector<CChatContainer*> >m_Container;`

```
class CChatContainer
{
public:
    CChatContainer()
    {
        m_uStartPos = 0;
        m_uEndPos = 0;
        m_dwColor = NULL;
        m_pItemElem = NULL;
    }
    ~CChatContainer(){};

    u_long m_uStartPos;
    u_long m_uEndPos;
    DWORD m_dwColor;
    void* m_pItemElem;
};
```

how do I insert values in it, the vector part seems very complex to me

Comment: `MyVector.push_back(new CChatContainer())`?

Comment: Can you just `m_Container[some_index].push_bask(some_c_char_container)`?

Comment: `map<u_long, std::vector<CChatContainer*> >::iterator it = m_Container.find( 5 );
 if( it != m_Container.end() )
  cout << it->second.at( 0 )->m_dwColor;` was kinda complicated tho

Comment: Do you really need pointers to `CChatContainer`? If you do, use `std::unique_ptr` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example:

```
u_long j = 2; // get index in the map - where to insert
std::vector<CChatContainer*> conts; // create container to insert
for( int i = 0; i < N; i++ ) { // fill the container
  CChatContainer* new_cont = new CChatContainer;
  cont.push_back(new_cont);
}

m_Container[j] = conts; // insert
```